# One or more OTLP metric data point(s) were dropped because New Relic does not fully support cumulative metrics over GRPC for FedRAMP customers

Tags: python, newrelic, open-telemetry

First time user of New Relic here. Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong about sending OTLP data to New Relic. My Python code is:

```py
otlp_metric_reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(
    OTLPMetricExporter(
        endpoint="https://otlp.eu01.nr-data.net:4317",
        headers={"api-key": "..."},
    )
)
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[otlp_metric_reader])
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)

meter = metrics.get_meter("my_service")
```

The metric I configured is:

```py
my_histogram = meter.create_histogram(
    "my_histogram",
    unit="ms",
    description="...",
)
```

I am emitting the metric as follows:

```py
start_time = perf_counter_ns()
try:
    await foo()
finally:
    my_histogram.record((perf_counter_ns() - start_time) / 1_000_000, {"foo": "bar"})
```

Querying for

```
SELECT message, metricName, name 
FROM NrIntegrationError 
WHERE newRelicFeature = 'Metrics' 
SINCE 5 HOURS AGO 
LIMIT 100
```

Shows:

> One or more OTLP metric data point(s) were dropped because New Relic does not fully support cumulative metrics over GRPC for FedRAMP customers. Histograms will be dropped and Sums will be ingested as Gauges. Try sending over HTTP instead.

Now, as you can see, I am using the Europe endpoint for OTLP. It's true, I am using the gRPC endpoint, but definitely nothing to do with FedRAMP.

Am I hitting some weird issue with New Relic? Or am I doing something wrong myself?

Answer (score 0):

There are specific endpoints for specific each category.

I think there are fedramp specific endpoints for otel. You might be using the wrong endpoint.

Comment: As you can see from my code snippet (which is a shortened version of the actual one), I am using the European OTLP endpoint, which has nothing to do with FedRAMP compliance.